# How to add a key value into an object that is in a separate function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object

I have this function:

```
     function TrackEvent(eventName, eventProperties) {
        eventProperties = {};
        eventProperties["history_section"] = "history"; 
        // Do something         
     }
```

And later I have this function:

```
function TrackHistoryChanges() { 
    $('btn').click(function () {
        eventProperties = {};
        eventProperties["updated_history"] = getHistory();
        TrackEvent("save changed", eventProperties); 
    })
}
```

My aim is to add the properties from the second function to the event properties object in the first function (rather than resetting it every time the first function is called), with the aim to add further later on in the code depending on what buttons are being clicked.

I am new to Javascript and cannot work out how to add to ADD to the existing eventProperties object with my second function. Please can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `eventProperties` looks like a global variable. How and where is it created?

Comment: Dos 'btn' exists as a valid element?It should be .btn or #btn or button I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we need more information about where these functions live, are they in the same file? are you doing any kind of importing/exporting, using webpack to build a bundle of some kind?

The short answer without knowing all of this is to declare the `eventProperties` variable somewhere outside both of those functions so that it can be accessed by both:

```
const eventProperties = {};

function trackEvent() {
  eventProperties.history_section = 'history';
}

function trackHistoryChanges() {
  ...etc
}
```

there are other approaches you can take but it all depends on how your files are set up. If you want the eventProperties to persist throughout the lifetime of the web session, you can also store the eventProperties in the global window object:

```
window.eventProperties = {};
```

this way you can access it from any of your files

Comment: Thanks @duxfox-- and sorry for not providing more information. Both functions are in the same file and no importing/exporting or webpack used. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove resetting eventProperties variable in TrackEvent function. In javascript objects passing by reference. You can read more about it on medium: [Pass By Reference In JavaScript](https://medium.com/nodesimplified/javascript-pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference-in-javascript-fcf10305aa9c).

So fixed code is:

```
function TrackEvent(eventName, eventProperties) {
    // Add new value to the object
    eventProperties["history_section"] = "history"; 
    // Do something
}

function TrackHistoryChanges() { 
    $('btn').click(function () {
        var eventProperties = {};
        eventProperties["updated_history"] = getHistory();
        TrackEvent("save changed", eventProperties); 
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Volodymyr but unfortunately I get the error that  "eventProperties is undefined" when calling the TrackEvent function :(